# Can Hadoop ReflectionUtils initialize enums?

Tags: java, hadoop, reflection, enums

I need to pass a list of Enum `Bucket` types between Mapper and Reducer, I have implemented custom `BucketArrayWritable` according to [implementation-of-an-arraywritable-for-a-custom-hadoop-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386781/implementation-of-an-arraywritable-for-a-custom-hadoop-type/4390928#4390928), and the `Bucket` Enum has a no-argument constructor, but I always get the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Bucket.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableFactories.newInstance(WritableFactories.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableFactories.newInstance(WritableFactories.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable.readFields(ArrayWritable.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKeyValue(ReduceContextImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKey(ReduceContextImpl.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.nextKey(WrappedReducer.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:449)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.turn.platform.profile.mapreduce.counting.Bucket.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
```

Reducer might want to use reflection to init object, but Enum constructors are private by default,

> [8.9.2 Enum Body Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)
>   In an enum declaration, a constructor declaration with no access modifiers is private.

I don't know wether it is because Hadoop ReflectionUtils cannot find private constructors

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;


public enum Bucket implements Writable{

    // right bound exclusive
    MAX((count) -> {
        if (count > getValue()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }, (count, _userId, incre) -> {
        value = count;
        userId = _userId;
    }),
    TOTAL((count) -> {
        return true;
    }),
    BUCKET_0_10((count) -> {
        if (count < 10) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }),
    BUCKET_10_100((count) -> {
        if (count >= 10 && count < 100) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    })
    ;

    private static long value = 0;
    private static LongWritable userId = new LongWritable(0);

    private TriConsumer<Long, LongWritable, Long> consumer;
    private Predicate<Long> predicator;

    Bucket() {

    }

    Bucket(Predicate<Long> predicator) {
        this.predicator = predicator;
    }

    Bucket(Predicate<Long> predicator, TriConsumer<Long, LongWritable, Long> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.predicator = predicator;
    }

    public static long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void setValue(long newVal) {
        value = newVal;
    }

    public TriConsumer<Long, LongWritable, Long> getConsumer() {
        if (consumer == null) {
            consumer = (count, _userId, incre) -> {
                setValue(getValue() + incre);
                userId = _userId;
            };
        }
        return consumer;
    }

    public Predicate<Long> getPredicator() {
        return predicator;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeLong(value);
        userId.write(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        value = in.readLong();
        userId.readFields(in);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ReflectionUtils` class tries to initialize the enum by reflection, but enums cannot be instantiated this way, this is stated in the Java Language Specification, and like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614325/6201659) says, is mainly to allow the use of `==` to compare enums. With reflection you can only obtain the existing references.

Regarding to the use of enums, you could 'wrap' the enum in a class, this way you can override the `equals` and `hashcode` method that is normally used in the reducers. Also depending on what you are doing `WritableUtils` has the methods `writeEnum` and `readEnum`. You can check more about how implement the wrapper class in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801338/6201659).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I actually have read all of those answers. I tried to use wrapper class to hold enums, but enums are static from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663834/in-java-are-enum-types-inside-a-class-static), and all instances of the wrapper class share the same enums, which is not I want, do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: From [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798485/java-objects-shared-variables), it seems like all instance of the wrapper class will share the same enums, so I think it is possible to pass enum between mapper and reducers

Comment: The first answer refers to nested enums, yes they are static. You should only use the enum to `difference` the class, your `Writable` is stateful, so you have to implement it in the class and then use the variables that you want for each instance, e.g. value shouldn't be static

Comment: Sorry, last comment should be impossible to pass enum as a class between mapper and reducer